# Unable to import tensorflow 1.10 with CUDA 9.2 installed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow GPU version. I had installed the tensorflow by pip install command it installs the latest version that is 1.10. Following a video I installed the CUDA toolkit latest version 9.2 and cudnn version 7.2.1 for CUDA 9.2. While importing I get an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
>       ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in 
>       self_check.preload_check()
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
>       % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
>   ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

Unable to understand why it is asking for the older version cudart64_90. Is I have to install the CUDA 9.0 or is this possible to do some changes in existing installation.

Comment: For now, pypi pre-built tensorflow only support cuda9.0. cudnn7. if you want cuda9.2, maybe you can build from source

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#tensorflow_gpu_support

Comment: can you plz tell me what do you mean by build from source ? @Bugkiller

Comment: @Ishaan By build from source, he means compile/install it yourself from tensorflow source code. Based on the fact that you had to ask, I don't think you're ready for a step like that. I think you'll have better luck if you just revert to CUDA 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

TF 1.10 prebuilt installer are not supported yet with Cuda 9.2. You can uninstall the TF 1.10 installed using the pre-installed binaries and then rebuilt TF for Cuda 9.2.

I just following the link below to build TF from its source for Cuda 9.2:

https://www.python36.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-9-2-for-python-on-ubuntu/2/

The instructions above are great and worked.